# Spring boot without database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

So one of the cool things I like about spring boot is that it can deploy its own jetty server when launched.

Is it possible to have spring boot deploy its own MySQL without having it installed on the machine?

I understand this sounds silly, but in my case I want database to be initialized every time I run spring boot, and I want it cleared up every time I stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the Spring Boot docs:

> Spring Boot can auto-configure embedded H2, HSQL and Derby databases. You don’t need to provide any connection URLs, simply include a build dependency to the embedded database that you want to use.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: nice! Thank you for you insight, somehow I missed that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [@streetturtle's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43395545/3493036) answer. You can also have an installed Database on your system and be able to create, update or drop the Database by starting and stoping your spring-boot application by using jpa.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`